# Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Expected type 'wc', but it was: a custom Vc object

Tags: javascript

The indicated error appears on line //line29, and I am not able to find the error within the code, can someone help me?
the code is to show the information of the registered users when it is searched through the cpf;

```
   const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
   const db = getFirestore(app);

async function GetADocument(){
var Ref =  setDoc(db, 'cpf', pesquisa.value);
const docSnap  = await getDocs(Ref);

  if(docSnap.exists(cpf = pesquisa)){
    nome.value = docSnap.data().nome;
    endereco.value = docSnap.data().endereco;
    bairro.value = docSnap.data().bairro;
    cidade.value = docSnap.data().cidade;
    uf.value = docSnap.data().uf;
    cep.value = docSnap.data().cep;
    rg.value = docSnap.data().rg;
    cpf.value = docSnap.data().cpf;
    nascimento.value = docSnap.data().nascimento;
    tel.value = docSnap.data().tel;
    cel.value = docSnap.data().cel;
    titulo.value = docSnap.data().titulo;
    zona.value = docSnap.data().zona;
    secao.value = docSnap.data().secao;
    pai.value = docSnap.data().pai;
    mae.value = docSnap.data().mae;
  }
   else{
    alert("usuário não encontrado");
   }
} //line29

btnbuscar.addEventListener("click", GetADocument);
```

Comment: Please could you add the actual error output to your question.

Comment: Also, from a quick glance, if this is the entirety of your code, you seem to have an extra `}` on line 29.

Answer (score 0):

`setDoc` is used to write a document. If you want to create a `DocumentReference` you need to use `doc`.

Try changing

```
var Ref =  setDoc(db, 'cpf', pesquisa.value);
```

to

```
var Ref = doc(db, 'cpf', pesquisa.value);
```

Also, `getDocs` (with an s) retrieves all documents in a collection. If you just want to fetch a single document you need to use `getDoc` (without an s).